# Binding pattern matches to identifiers in Racket

Tags: pattern-matching, racket

Is there an easy way to imitate the `as` keyword from OCaml like this:

```
(match x with
 |((a,b) as c, d) -> c)
```

in Racket? I thought about defining a syntax rule in order to handle the syntax `((exp) as id)`, but then I run across the issue of exp potentially having more `as` bindings. Any thoughts on how I might be able to extract all the `as` bindings from an expression and then give them a local binding in the expression of the match clause? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about how to do this with Racket’s built-in `match` macro, or some custom pattern-matching macro you’re writing?

Comment: You can use the `and` pattern for that

Comment: @AlexisKing Either one, but if Racket has a built-in way, that'd be better obviously.

Comment: @AlexKnauth That did the trick, thanks!